# sidekiq running even when removed from app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a problem that sidekiq process is using almost all of my server CPU.
Today I removed sidekiq from the app but still when I run `htop` it shows heavy CPU usage from `usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq`.

The weirdest thing is that the sidekiq was implemented about 5 months ago but the problem started to occur only recently (around two weeks ago).

I'm using sidekiq only for one background job.

I have tryed to run `killall sidekiq` on server to kill all sidekiq processes but nothing happens.

Here is my pretty simple sidekiq worker:

```
class UserWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)

    url = "http://url_to_external_api"

    uri = URI.parse(url)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
        http.request(request)
    end

    age = JSON.parse(response.body)['user']['age']

    user.age = age
    user.save!

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    # nothing to do here
end
end
```

At this point I'm pretty desperate because this sidekiq process is killing my server every other day and I can't even remove it completely.

**EDIT:**
When I run `kill -9 PID` to kill the process, it gets killed but right after that it's starts up again with another PID.

**QUESTION**

I just manually run the command `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq -r /var/www/path to my application` on Amazon Ec2 instance and I got error: `Error fetching message: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)`
So do I need to install redis on the server to run sidekiq?

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could suggest just how to kill this process

Comment: cosidering that it process respawns, is the sidekiq worker really removed from your Procfile? also , are there other RoR apps using Sidekiq and hosted on the same box?